# SharePoint InfoPath display form - how to open in edit mode after button click

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, button

I have created a display form in InfoPath for a SharePoint list.

On the display form I have a visible control image button called 'Edit'.

When I click the button in display mode I switch to another view.

The problem is the new view is opening in display mode and not edit mode.

How can I control what mode the new view is opening in when the 'edit button' is clicked?

Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have checked "read only" in the new view. make sure to uncheck it by changing it in the properties option located just under the view tab
[image]

Hopefully this helps :)